# How to migrate from RAIDZ1 to RAIDZ2 using ZFS-native?

Tags: server, raid, zfs

Last night I created a raidz1 array, however later in the evening I realised I needed to create a raidz2 (RAID5), is it possible to change the raid level of my array from raidz1 to raidz2 without destroying the data on the drives?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How did you set up ZFS on Ubuntu Linux? This is not a Linux native file system. I know of an external project and a FUSE approach.

Comment: I used this tutorial: http://zefr.wordpress.com/tag/zfs/

Comment: Please **edit** your question with extra information. This is a Q&A site, rather than a discussion forum. Also, your link is basically just a blog and not a single how-to. Based on the blog contents I believe you used [this ZFS-native PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable). Please also incorporate more of your set up, (pool set up, disks, etc.). Keep in mind that ZFS is not a Ubuntu/Linux file system, so it will be hard to get support here. If you don't get response here, consider asking it on unix.stackexchange.com instead where more ZFS-people are active.

Comment: That is correct I did install the ZFS syetem using the ppa, I then created a zpool with my disks 3 x 1TB. Last night I destroyed the Raidz0+1 and created a RaidZ2 as I couldn't find a solution. I'm now copying over the data again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilt the array using RaidZ2 instead as I couldn't see a way of changing it over.

Thanks anyway.